# dotnetnuke missing installation stylesheet

Tags: installation, dotnetnuke

I'm trying my first install of DNN on a local machine and it appears that the stylesheet is missing from the Install/InstallWizard.aspx file - I can see the forms and text but as black and white but it's not styled. I've tried deleting it and re-downloading from the codeplex site but nothing is working, any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try and ensure that you have "unblocked" the ZIP file before extracting the contents.

1. Right Click
2. Choose Properties
3. Click on Unblock (if available)
4. Extract Zip.

If that doesn't work, I would load the developer tools for your browser and see if you can see why the CSS file isn't loading (404 error, or something else)